# Hide Angular environment variables from browser console

Tags: angular, environment-variables, api-key

I've an Angular application that uses the environment file to store WebApi url and WebApi Key, similar to this:

```json
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  API_1_URL: 'https://localhost:99999/api/Api1',
  API_2_URL: 'https://localhost:99999/api/Api2',
};

export const API_KEY = {
  API_1_KEY: 'Key1',
  API_2_KEY: 'Key2'
}
```

The problem is that now the API_KEY are visibile in the browser console.

Is there a way to hide this variables (especially for the API_KEY)?

I've tried a solution similar to [this](https://pazel.dev/how-to-keep-your-secrets-from-your-source-code-in-an-angular-project), but the keys are still visible in the console after the build.

Comment: No, there isn't. Even if you obfuscated or encrypted them, you'd also have to include the code to reverse that (and given the values are presumably used in requests, looking at the network tab would show the plain values with no effort). Angular's environment feature bakes the values into the bundle, if you want to keep the keys secret you need a backend that will proxy calls to the other endpoints.

Comment: Thanks.
If you put your comment as answer, i will mark as correct answer.