# Hide Angular environment variables with Angular Universal

Tags: angular, environment-variables, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

With [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76118503/hide-angular-environment-variables-from-browser-console) thread I've discovered that is not possible to hide Angular environment variables from browser console.

I've now discovered the Server Side rendering of Angular ([SSR](https://angular.io/guide/universal)) with Angular Universal.

Can this technology allow me to hide this environment variables in some way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Angular universal renders complete responses. Assume ANY data you send to the browser as exposed and readable client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is not possible to separate the environment variables of angular by using angular universal. But if you have the urgency to hide the variable and make sure that they are not available on the browser end you can try out a particular way that is, store the variable in the .env file of the server. If you are using express then you can store that file on the server and use them on your angular application. But as they are only available to the server they will not be exposed to the browser app.

You can follow various ways to access this variables on the server. You can provide it as an optional parameter, use a call angular to the server. Even, if you only need it on the server end you can directly access it using process.env , I once tried it and worked. but won't recommend it